# Getting html variables with c#

Tags: c#

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Text = this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString() + "/" + (object)this.comboBox1.Items.Count;
            string str = new WebClient().DownloadString("webpage.com" + this.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            if (!str.Contains("Message"))
                this.listBox1.Items.Add((object)this.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            else if (str.ToLower().Contains(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()))
                ;
            ++this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
        }
        catch
        {
            if (this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex != this.comboBox1.Items.Count - 1)
                return;
            this.timer1.Stop();
        }
    }
```

I want to check whether the url page contains a specific html class name in the page its on html code

Comment: In this code I have  if (!str.Contains("Message")) but i want that to be if page contains the class name i want to check for

Comment: Have you looked at the [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) yet? It makes finding parts of a HTML page much easier

Comment: I already know waht I want to find I need to make my code find it on a page

Comment: The right way is probably via HtmlAgilityPack as per @ScottChamberlain.  The quick way that will fail in the future in fun and exciting ways is via Grep string searches for the magic message/Class you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to use HtmlAgilityPack then you could try something like this:

```
str.Contains("class=\"" + nameOfClass)
```

I would also recommend to remove whitespaces before comparison.

Comment: so the page if it has the thing I want it has

Comment: <button class="DMButton u-sizeFull js-tooltip btn primary-btn tweet-action tweet-btn" type="button" data-name="Golden Rey" data-screen-name="Golden" data-user-id="1826201" data-original-title="Send a Direct Message to x">
  <span class="DMButton-content button-text tweeting-text u-textTruncate">
    <span class="DMButton-icon Icon Icon--dmCompose Icon--medium"></span><span class="DMButton-text" aria-hidden="true">Message</span>
  </span>
</button>

Comment: how do i use what you gave above to check which person has dm enabled on their profile

Comment: i want it to check if the class dmbutton is on the page it checks aka url